# After Insert trigger not working in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am trying to set trigger in mysql.
actually i am trying to insert last inserted record from notes table into log_trigger but below code is not working.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_note` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `notes`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_trigger (NoteId, customerContact, customer, users, note, NoteCreatedTs) 
    SELECT Id, customerContact, customer, users, note, CreatedBy FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referencing the physical row from the actual notes table, reference the `New` pseudo row (which will match the column definitions of the underlying table being triggered):

```
INSERT INTO log_trigger (NoteId, customerContact, customer, users, note, NoteCreatedTs)   
SELECT New.PostId, New.customerContact, New.customer, New.users, New.note, New.CreatedBy;
```

`New` will already contain the newly inserted row - you don't need to find it again.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fc76/1)

Comment: hi StuartLC, i want to insert last record from 'notes' table into 'log_trigger' table.

Comment: Your trigger is on table `notes`, and you are selecting the last row from notes. The `new` pseudo row contains the newly inserted row. Have you looked at the SqlFiddle example? See how it adds the newly inserted row from notes into log_trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `select` to select last data from the same table where the trigger is used. You can use `new` keyword for the same.

```
delimiter //

create trigger after_note after insert on notes
for each row 
begin
insert into log_trigger 
(NoteId, customerContact, customer, users, note, NoteCreatedTs)
values
(new.id,new.customerContact,new.customer,new.users,new.note,new.CreatedBy);
end;//

delimiter ;
```